# How to use CountDownTimer in RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**Why not anser to my question after 2 days? :(**

In my application I want use **CountDownTimer** into **RecyclerView** and I can show timer into this. 
But after scrolling items, not continued timer! start again timer! 
I want when scrolling on item continue timer from previous time, not start again! 
My Adapter codes:

```
class TestsAdapter @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TestsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var items = emptyList<Data>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemTestsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.bind(items[position])

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = position

    override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemTestsBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        var timer: CountDownTimer? = null

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        fun bind(item: Data) {
            binding.apply {
                item.apply {
                    titleTxt.text = "${context.getString(R.string.test)} $testPlanId"
                    timeTxt.text = time
                    //Btn
                    device?.let {
                        if (it.slug == PC) {
                            submitTypeTxt.text = context.getString(R.string.activeInPC)
                            submitBtnCard.backgroundTintList =
                                ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.lightGray4))
                        } else initSubmitBtn(item, binding, this@ViewHolder)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initSubmitBtn(data: Data, binding: ItemTestsBinding, holder: ViewHolder) {
        var bgColor = 0
        var typeText = ""
        binding.apply {
            when (data.state) {
                ACCEPT -> {
                    typeText = context.getString(R.string.start)
                    bgColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.ufoGreen)
                    data.remainedTime?.let {
                        if (it > 0) {
                            initTimer(it, binding, holder)
                        }
                    }
                    submitInfoTxt.isVisible = true
                }

                PENDING -> {
                    typeText = context.getString(R.string.register)
                    bgColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.dodgerBlue)
                    submitInfoTxt.isVisible = false
                }

                RESERVABLE -> {
                    typeText = context.getString(R.string.reservable)
                    bgColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.sunglow)
                    submitInfoTxt.isVisible = false
                }
            }
            submitBtnCard.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(bgColor)
            submitTypeTxt.text = typeText
        }
    }

    private fun initTimer(time: Long, binding: ItemTestsBinding, holder: ViewHolder) {
        if (holder.timer != null) holder.timer!!.cancel()
        holder.timer = object : CountDownTimer(time, 1_000) {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                var timer = millisUntilFinished
                val day: Long = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(timer)
                timer -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(day)
                val hours: Long = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timer)
                timer -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours)
                val minutes: Long = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timer)
                timer -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes)
                val seconds: Long = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timer)
                binding.submitInfoTxt.text = "$minutes:$seconds"
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                binding.submitInfoTxt.text = context.getString(R.string.finish)
            }
        }.start()
    }

    private var onItemClickListener: ((Data, String, String) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Data, String, String) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }

    fun setData(data: List<Data>) {
        val adapterDiffUtils = BaseDiffUtils(items, data)
        val diffUtils = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(adapterDiffUtils)
        items = data
        diffUtils.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }
}
```

I searched many times into StackOverFlow, Google, Youtube but now found any solution!
How can I fix it?